# Why do droids in Star Wars all have random alphanumeric designations?

Tags: star-wars

R2D2, C3PO, BB8 and so on. Is there an explanation in-universe and out of universe for this naming protocol?

Comment: I checked that, and that was asking about four character designations and it was refuted. I'm asking about the origin of the naming convention.

Comment: @Broklynite The answer to the linked question is "contracted form of manufacturer serial numbers", which would seem like the answer to this one as well

Comment: Whoops I miswrote the question- meant in and out of universe. Stupid cellphone :/ updated accordingly

Comment: Protocol? Have you ever looked at model names for TVs and other electronic equipment? Sometimes their protocols seem to be indistinguishable from gibberish.